# How to connect points on a Matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I wrote the code to get the relationship between the two variables. The code is as follows:

```
for fn=0.1:0.1:10
    for Qe= [0.1,0.5, 1, 5]
        fn2=fn.*fn;
        Mg=abs((Ln*fn2)/(((Ln+1)*(fn2)-1)+1i*(((fn2)-1).*fn.*Qe*Ln)));
        semilogx(fn,Mg,'b','linewidth',7); 
        hold on;
        save;
    end
end
```

[image]
However, The curves I got are scatters points. I want to get all points to be connected. When I increase the step point for fn, i.e fn=0.1:0.001:10, it is better, but it takes a very long time.

Comment: How do you call your plot function? YOu probably need to provide LineData for describing what kind of line you'd want...

Comment: @DaMachk `semilogx` is a plot function.

Comment: Try `'b-'` in `semilogx`. If that doesn't help, there are either nans in your data, or each of your data sets are single data points. Plotting commands can only connect points within the same call to `plot/semilogx`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you plot a single point every iteration. Let the loops run their course, save the points as vectors, then call a single plot at the end plotting the vectors, which will automatically generate connected lines.

```
fn=0.1:0.1:10
Qe= [0.1,0.5, 1, 5]
Mg = zeros(numel(fn),numel(Qe)); %initialise output
for ii=1:numel(fn)
    fn2=fn(ii)^2;
    for jj = 1:numel(Qe)
        Mg(ii,jj)=abs((Ln*fn2)/(((Ln+1)*(fn2)-1)+1i*(((fn2)-1).*fn(ii).*Qe(jj)*Ln))); %save in matrix form
    end
end

figure
hold on;
semilogx(fn,Mg(:,1),'b','linewidth',7); % Generate plots with different colours
semilogx(fn,Mg(:,2),'r','linewidth',7);
semilogx(fn,Mg(:,3),'y','linewidth',7);
semilogx(fn,Mg(:,4),'g','linewidth',7);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, now I can understand where was my problem. However, I tried your improved code but there is an error in line of "Mg(ii,jj)=abs..." saying Matrix dimension must agree, and I can't see why!

Comment: @Mr.Noah You probably shouldn't accept the answer if it's not working. I missed out on a `fn` in that formula, so it cane out an array, and not a single element. As you have not provided the other input (`Ln`), I can't check whether this were all faults. Just as a side note: that's one of the easiest errors MATLAB can throw at you: check the size of the LHS, check that of the RHS and they won't match if that's the error.

Comment: Of course, if it doesn't work I'd like to know why, and I can try to solve it. If it works now (which it does in case `Ln` is a scalar), feel free to accept again.

Comment: The Ln value equals 8. I tried it but it didn't work until I could found the below solution, but it is a little bit slow. I'm really grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it using this code. It could solve the problem, however, it is a little bit slow (

```
    %%Parameters%%
Ln=8;
Mgmin=0.88;
Mgmax=1.18;
Qe= [0.25,0.3,0.35,0.7,1.65,4,8];
c= {'b','m','r','g','y','c','k'};
%%Gain Vs Frequecny Function%%
fn=0.1:0.001:10;
fn2=fn.*fn;
%%Gain Curve%%
figure;
for j=1:7 
    for i=1:9901
        Mg(i)=abs((Ln*(fn2(i)))/(((Ln+1)*(fn2(i))-1)+1i*(((fn2(i))-1).*fn(i).*Qe(j)*Ln)));
    end;
    semilogx(fn,Mg,c{j},'linewidth',3);
    hold on;
    plot(fn,Mgmax,'k');
    hold on;
    plot(fn,Mgmin,'k');
    save;
end;
```

Comment: The plot function is quite expensive, and now you call it about 70000 times. So yeah, if you want to get any performance make sure to completely process your data *before* calling plot.